# Using GetKeyState for triple key combinations does not work

Tags: autohotkey

In the following script,when I press the CapsLock and Alt keys and then the J key,"is work" message will not pop up. Only by simultaneously pressing the CapsLock, Alt, and J keys and immediately releasing the keys will "it work" message pop up.

```
CapsLock & J::
if GetKeyState("Alt","p"){
    MsgBox  is work
}
return
```

Change the key J to K, as follows:

```
CapsLock & K::
if GetKeyState("Alt","p"){
    MsgBox  is work
}
return
```

This allows you to press the CapsLock and Alt keys first and then the K key to pop up the "it work" message. I tried other keys, such as A, S, D, F, H, and so on.But you can't change it to G. Only three keys can be pressed at the same time and immediately release the normal output "is work"

I don't understand why?

When custom key combinations use GetKeyState, what is the order in which the keys are executed?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you trigger your hotkey by pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd> it's looking to see if <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed. So if there is any delay between when the hotkey is triggered and <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed, then your `MsgBox` won't show.

To get it to work every time, start by holding the key that `GetKeyState` is looking for (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) and then hold your other keys in order from left to right as listed. So, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then hold <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, then press <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: But if I press Alt and CapsLock(The two keys are not released) and then press j, it's not going to work. If I press k, it's going to work.

Comment: I used "key history and script info" to test the key. When I pressed Alt and CapsLock and then j, I failed to detect that j was pressed. When I change the k key, I can detect it. Could it be the keyboard problem?

Comment: Hmmm, on my machine it seems to work fine (that is, alt + capslock + j works). Are you certain there are no other conflicting hotkeys or scripts running?